# How to Insert data from CSV file to SQL Server with specific columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple csv files with same pattern of columns (450 columns). I need to take only one column that is in 340th position and insert that column data to SQL Server 2016. I can use bulk insert, but before this i need to create a temp table of 450 columns which takes a long time. Is there any other methods available that i can use to take only specific column (340th column) and insert its data to SQL Server?

Comment: Use an ETL tool, such as SSIS?

Comment: Yes, but As per the organizations instructions, I have to use SQL Server Query Only.

Comment: Use [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: As i am trying to do this but how to create .fmt file schema for my csv file ?

Comment: Are these true CSV files, or are they fixed-width? If they're true CSVs, you don't need a `.fmt` file for `OPENROWSET`

Comment: the csv file is delimited with (;)

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server import export wizard to dump the specific column data. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSIS for soemething like this.  Bulk Insert would work too, but it's going to take a bit more work to get setup and working.

```
create table test (field1 varchar(255), field2 varchar(255), field3 varchar(255))
go
bulk insert test
from 'c:\myFilePath\mycsv.csv'
with 
(fieldterminator=',',
rowterminator='\n'
)

ALTER TABLE test DROP column [field1]
```

Or...Bulk Insert everything into a staging table and from there load what you need into your final mater table.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) can do this. You basically will upload the csv files, ADF will create a JSON template from the CSV structure (you can also edit this manually). And then during the import step. you just remove the unwanted columns from the import JSON template and hit play.

Follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool